# Netcdf C++| How to write a record for single variables?

Tags: c++, netcdf

I have a function to initialize a netcdf file, then one to write fields. Here are they :

```
void initNc(string name){
  NcFile myfile(name.c_str(), NcFile::Replace);
  NcDim *xdim = myfile.add_dim("xdim", NX);
  NcDim *tdim = myfile.add_dim("tdim");
  myfile.add_var("x", ncDouble, tdim, xdim);
  myfile.add_var("vx", ncDouble, tdim, xdim);
}
```

and

```
void writeToNcFile(double *x, string name, string varname){
  NcFile myfile(name.c_str(), NcFile::Write);
  NcDim *tdim = myfile.get_dim("tdim");
  NcVar *xvar = myfile.get_var(varname.c_str());
  long sz = tdim->size();
  xvar->set_rec(sz);
  xvar->put_rec(x);
  myfile.close();
}
```

For one variable (here in my init function example I have two), and calling several times writeToNcFile, this is working fine, appending results following the record dimension. However, as soon as I have two variables (as in this example, called x and vx), and I call one function for each variable (so, two calls), it puts a record for each variable PER call to function! Here is the content of the file for example for NX=10:

```
dimensions:
xdim = 10 ;
tdim = UNLIMITED ; // (2 currently)
variables:
    double x(tdim, xdim) ;
    double vx(tdim, xdim) ;
data:
 x =
  0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9,
  _, _, _, _, _, _, _, _, _, _ ;
 vx =
  _, _, _, _, _, _, _, _, _, _,
  0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18 ;}
```

How can I go around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error comes from the fact that the writing function is called once for each variable, closing the file between each call. So that a record is put for all the variables in the nc file each time the function is called.
One solution is to write all the fields for one record inside only one function.